# Monaco Editor web workers are registered wrongly, return 404

Tags: laravel, vue.js, web-worker, vite, monaco-editor

Mounted a small app to edit some JSON files. This app uses Monaco-Editor, under Vue 3 and Vite 3. I followed instructions as per Evan Yu (the Vue creator) [posted on twitter](https://twitter.com/youyuxi/status/1355316139144970240), to no avail.

```
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor";
import editorWorker from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker?worker";
import jsonWorker from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker?worker";
import cssWorker from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker?worker";
import htmlWorker from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker?worker";
import tsWorker from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker?worker";
import yamlWorker from "monaco-yaml/yaml.worker?worker";

self.MonacoEnvironment = {
    getWorker(_, label) {
        switch (label) {
            case 'json':
                return new jsonWorker();
            case 'css':
            case 'scss':
            case 'less':
                return new cssWorker();
            case 'html':
            case 'handlebars':
            case 'razor':
                return new htmlWorker();
            case 'typescript':
            case 'javascript':
                return new tsWorker();
            case 'yaml':
                return new yamlWorker();
            default:
                return new editorWorker()
        }
    }
};

monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setEagerModelSync(true);

let instance = null

onMounted(() => {
    instance = monaco.editor.create(container.value, {
        value: '{"foo":"bar"}',
        language: 'json',
        tabSize: 2,
    })
})

onUnmounted(() => {
    instance?.dispose()
})
```

The result is Vite returning the workers URL wrongly, appending `http://localhost` to them.

[image: Vite requesting wrong Web Workers URL paths]

I tried again disabling both [Laravel Vite Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-vite-plugin) plugin, using the [Vue plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitejs/plugin-vue) with default, to which the URL now pointed directly to `localhost` instead of the Vite server (`[::1]:5173`) that contains them:

[image: Vite requesting the workers to localhost]

Note that Vite imports the worker chunks without problem, but once the `MonacoEnvironment.getWorker()` returns them, the URL gets manipulated wrongly. The worker URL of these append `/` to t
he resulting URL.

[image: The worker URL appended with "/"]

```js
// Transcript
// HTTP 1.1 GET http://[::1]:5173/node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker.js?worker

export default function WorkerWrapper() {
    return new Worker("/http:://[::1]:5173/node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker.js?type=module&worker_file",{type:"module"})
}
```

At this point I'm quite lost. Seems that the Vue Plugin or Laravel Plugin config has something to do, since I'm working on Laravel right now, but I'm unable to debug where the calls to these workers are done, and how the URL is built to pinpoint where is the cause.

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin"
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: "resources/js/app.js",
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            // @see https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#vue
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                // Needed to build the worker file chunks in production.
                manualChunks: {
                    JsonWorker: ["monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker"],
                    CssWorker: ["monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker"],
                    HtmlWorker: ["monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker"],
                    TsWorker: ["monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker"],
                    EditorWorker: ["monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker"],
                    YamlWorker:["monaco-yaml/yaml.worker"]
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: What does this question have to do with PHP or Laravel? It seems to only be about client side?

Comment: @M.Eriksson PHP tag was muscle memory, sorry. About the images, I'll change those copy-pasteable.